# got an error on whille copy and paste the codegintor project on server

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

i was copied the code and paste on the server to another server.
this the codegintor project and having sparks installed.and when am run the second server 
Error is

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ActiveRecord\DatabaseException'
>   with message 'exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[28000]
>   [1045] Access denied for user 'hktest1_myaccou'@'localhost' (using
>   password: YES)'
>   /home/hktest1/public_html/engineering/sparks/php-activerecord/0.0.2/vendor/php-activerecord/lib/Table.php(103):
>   ActiveRecord\ in
>   /home/hktest1/public_html/engineering/sparks/php-activerecord/0.0.2/vendor/php-activerecord/lib/Connection.php
>   on line 241 .

Can any one help appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your configuration is attempting to connect as the mysql user  using some password.  may be the password is wrong.  In general it's best to have a user specifically for the database needed by the application, but that's more an aside as it is irrelevant to the problem you are currently having.

I would diagnose this using the mysql command line client in a shell, or phpMyAdmin.  Regardless, this is why I stated that its's a username password issue.  The only other issue would be the host, if for some reason the mysql server was on another machine, but I'm going to assume that is not your problem.

Also check if PDO is enabled or not. - pdo_mysql